# I got an error [Type "View Controller" does not conform to protocol "ORKTaskViewControllerDelegate"]

Tags: researchkit, swift3.2

I am just starting to use swift3 in Xcode in order to utilize ResearchKit provided by Apple.inc.
Although I have worked through tutorials from Researchkit Tutorial with Swift: Getting started in Ray Wenderlich, I have a trouble in the extension of ViewController. The following is my code.

```
import ResearchKit
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  @IBAction func consentTapped(sender : AnyObject) {
    let taskViewController = ORKTaskViewController(task: ConsentTask, taskRun: nil)
    taskViewController.delegate = self
    present(taskViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}

extension ViewController: ORKTaskViewControllerDelegate {

  func taskViewController(taskViewController: ORKTaskViewController, didFinishWithReason
         reason: ORKTaskViewControllerFinishReason, error: NSError?) {
    //Handle results with taskViewController.result
    taskViewController.dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've missed to add delegate. Add `ORKTaskViewControllerDelegate` to ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,ORKTaskViewControllerDelegate {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad(
   }
}
```